# How can I use Assert in Unit Testing?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

```
package htmlunit;

import org.junit.Assert;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net");
        Assert.assertEquals("HtmlUnit - Welcome to HtmlUnit", page.getTitleText());

        final String pageAsXml = page.asXml();
        Assert.assertTrue(pageAsXml.contains("<body class=\"composite\">"));

        final String pageAsText = page.asText();
        Assert.assertTrue(pageAsText.contains("Support for the HTTP and HTTPS protocols"));

        if(Assert.assertTrue(pageAsText.contains("Support for the HTTP and HTTPS protocols"))){
            System.out.println("true");
        } else {
            System.out.println("false");
        }

        System.out.println("test");
        webClient.closeAllWindows();
    }
}
```

Why I run this in Eclipse, then this returns only "test"? How can I print results from Asserts?

```
        if(Assert.assertTrue(pageAsText.contains("Support for the HTTP and HTTPS protocols"))){
            System.out.println("true");
        } else {
            System.out.println("false");
        }
```

I have that error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to boolean

How can I use `if` with `Assert`?

Comment: You need to read more about JUnit and the suggested structure of unit tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Assert.assertTrue` is void return. It throws an exception if its input is not true. This is useful in tests that you want to crash to indicate there is a problem.

Looks like in your case you just want `if(condition)`, not `if(Assert.assertTrue(condition))`. You don't actually have a use case for Assert.

Answer (score 4):

`assertTrue()` is declared to return `void`, so you cannot use it as the expression of an `if` statement. JUnit assertions will automatically print an error message when they fail, as long as you use them correctly within the JUnit framework.

Comment: Ok, so why this not show me any messages from junit?

Comment: @darlik Because you are not using the JUnit framework at all other than the Assert class. I suggest you do some research and read up about how to organize code in a JUnit test.